# Axios Basic Auth Header client id and client secret not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have below python code which is working perfect

```
token_url="https://<apiurl>.com/api/rest/oauth/token"
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
access_token_response=""
try:
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=data, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, auth=(client_id, client_secret))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
tokens = json.loads(access_token_response.text)
print("Token Generated Successfully")
return tokens
```

But in axios it is not working

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  axios.request({
    method: 'post',
    url: "/api/rest/oauth/token",
    baseURL: "https://<apiurl>.com",
    data: {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'scope': 'public'}, 
    auth: {
      username: "client id",
      password: "client secret"
     }
   }).then(function(response) {
      resolve(response)
      console.log(response)
   }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }) 

   })
```

getting 401 error any help would be great for us

Comment: Why `withCredentials: true`? You don't appear to be using cookies

Comment: still not working I removed withCredentials

Comment: In the JavaScript version, the API route is different! Is it a misspelling? `url: "/api/rest/oauth/token"` != `api/rest/oath/token`. Notice the `oauth` word.

Comment: I didn't say to remove `withCredentials`, I asked you why it was there

Comment: @Mr R  yes here I did mistake let me update the question

Comment: Inspect the content of both HTTP requests - the Axios and the Python one (e.g. using Fiddler or CharlesProxy). You will immediately see where the difference is and why you get 401 error.

Comment: `client_id, client_secret` in python seem to be in variables, while in js they are hardcoded strings.. could be a misspelling or similar.. also, try adding some `user-agent`, just in case..